# Interval order dimension of a Poset

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Definition $1$:

A poset $P=(X, \prec)$ is called Interval order if there exists a function $f$ which maps each $x \in X$ to an interval $I_x$ of real line such that $x \prec y$ iff $I_x \prec I_y$ ($I_x$ lies totally to the left of $I_y$).

Definition $2$:

Interval order dimension of a poset $P$ is minimum number $k$ of interval orders $P_1, \cdots, P_k$  such that $P= P_1 \cap \cdots \cap P_k$ i.e.,
 $x \prec y$ iff $x \prec_i y$ for all $i=1, \cdots, k$.

Q1: Is true that all $P_i$'s are defined on $X$ (or subset of $X$).

I am unable to understand the Definition $2$ properly. 
Can someone explain me with some examples?

Comment: What does $I_x \prec I_y$ mean, then?

Comment: $I_x$ lies totally to the left of $I_y$

Comment: And are the $I_x$s real intervals, or can they be intervals in an arbitrary total order? Do singletons count as intervals?

Comment: Real Intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example may help a bit with the notion of interval order dimension. Consider the poset $P$ whose Hasse diagram is shown below.

```
         b    d  
         |    |  
         a    c
```

Suppose that $P$ is an interval order, with intervals $I_a=[x_a,y_a],I_b=[x_b,y_b],I_c=[x_c,y_c]$, and $I_d=[x_d,y_d]$.

- Since $a\prec b$, $y_a<x_b$, and since $c\prec d$, $y_c<x_d$.
- Since $c\not\prec b$, $y_c\not<x_b$, i.e., $x_b\le y_c$.

Then $y_a<x_b\le y_c<x_d$, so $y_a<x_d$, and hence $I_a\prec I_d$. But this is impossible, since $a\not\prec d$. Thus, $P$ cannot be an interval order.

However, even though $\prec$, the partial order on $P$, is not itself an interval order, it *is* the intersection of two interval orders. This means that the interval order dimension of $P$ is $2$.

To see this, consider the two partial orders on $\{a,b,c,d\}$ whose Hasse diagrams are shown below:

```
         d               b  
         |\              |  
         b c             a d  
         |               |/
         a               c
```

- Check that each of these is an interval order. For the first, for instance, you can use the intervals $I_a=[0,1],I_b=[2,3],I_c=[0,3]$, and $I_d=[4,5]$.

Now denote these orders by $\prec_1$ and $\prec_2$, respectively, and for $i=1,2$ let $P_i$ be the set $\{a,b,c,d\}$ with the strict partial order $\prec_i$.

- Show that for $p,q\in\{a,b,c,d\}$, $p\prec q$ if and only if $p\prec_1 q$ and $p\prec_2 q$.

In other words, the strict partial order $\prec$ is the intersection of the two interval orders $\prec_1$ and $\prec_2$. Since $\prec$ is not itself an interval order, and it *is* the intersection of two interval orders, its interval order dimension must be $2$: that’s the smallest number of interval orders whose intersection is $\prec$.

In the notation that you’re using, $P=P_1\cap P_2$. This notation is extremely sloppy: a poset is actually an ordered pair whose first element is the set of elements — in my example $\{a,b,c,d\}$ — and whose second element is the set of ordered pairs making up the partial ordering relation — my example the relations $\prec,\prec_1$, and $\prec_2$ for the three different posets involved. It’s the *partial order relations* that are actually being intersected: the underlying set (here $\{a,b,c,d\}$) remains the same.

By the way, it turns out that a partial order is an interval order if and only if it does *not* contain an isomorphic copy of the four-element partial order $P$ at the beginning of this answer. My example proves one direction of this result; the proof of the other direction is harder.

Answer (score 1):

The notation $P_1 \cap \cdots\cap P_k$ is a little strange, but what makes best sense in context is that $P_1=(X, R_1)$, $P_2=(X,R_2)$ and so forth are all partial orders *on the same set $X$*, and $P_1 \cap \cdots\cap P_k$ then means $(X,R_1 \cap\cdots\cap R_k)$. It is easy to see that this is a poset.

Definition 2 now invites you to consider some poset $(X,\prec)$ and consider whether $\prec$ can be written as the intersection of interval orderings of $X$. It turns out that this is always the case, at least if $X$ is at most countable. Every countable *linear* order is an interval ordering (prove this!), and a partial order is the intersection of all its linear extensions (prove this too!).

The interval order dimension of $(X,\prec)$ is now the *smallest* cardinality $\kappa$ such that there $\prec$ can be written as the intersection of $\kappa$ interval orderings.